# mod_cluster application for load balancing in JBoss cluster

Tags: apache, jboss, mod-cluster

I have to create a system with JBoss in cluster modality with a load balancer using Apache HTTPD with mod_cluster.

I have configured the system correctly, and the load balancer see all nodes of the system. But, I have to create the web application for the load balancer now.
It has to be a servlet or a REST service that has a reference to a remote bean and make a lookup with JNDI? Or is something different?

Can someone provide to me a reference to a documentation/tutorial that explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_cluster is a Apache module that does the HTTP(S) load balancing.
Read more here: http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/

The whole application is installed in JBoss mod_cluster just does the load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

mod_cluster is just for load balancing. Just deploy the web app against the server group created. It gets deployed on master and slaves and can access the remote bean as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can dig into our mod_cluster testing servlets on [clusterbench/clusterbench](https://github.com/clusterbench/clusterbench) or [vastly simplified, lobotomized version](https://github.com/Karm/clusterbench/tree/simplified-and-pure).

All new documentation effort is accumulated on: http://modcluster.io

## TL;DR

- create any servlet application
- deploy to your workers and it's good to go
- if you want web sessions replicated in the cluster, add `<distributable/>` to your `WEB-INF/web.xml`